# How to make distance meter in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a distance meter. But I am not getting what I wanted. so I uploaded a picture. I want curved distance but I am getting straight something like displacement.

[image]

Here is my Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DistanceMeter : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject current;
    public GameObject destination;
    private float beginPos;
    private float targetPos;
    private float currPos;
    public Text dist;

    void Start()
    {
        beginPos = current.transform.position.x;
        targetPos = destination.transform.position.x;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        currPos = current.transform.position.x - targetPos;
        int Distance = Mathf.Abs(Mathf.RoundToInt (currPos));
        dist.text = Distance.ToString()+ " meters";
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest asking this question in math.stackexchange.com

Comment: the question seems a bit incomplete, does your object moves along a curve or otherwise what is the radius of the curve?

Comment: yes, object moving along the curve.

Comment: It's just math: http://www.had2know.com/academics/parabola-segment-arc-length-area.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accumulate the traveled distance to find out the traveled distance on the curve:

```
public class DistanceMeter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject current;
    public GameObject destination;
    private float beginPos;
    private float targetPos;
    private float currPos;
    private float displacement;
    public Text dist;

    void Start()
    {
        beginPos = current.transform.position.x;
        targetPos = destination.transform.position.x;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float currDelta = current.transform.position.x - currPos;
        currPos = current.transform.position.x;
        displacement += Mathf.Abs(currDelta);
        dist.text = displacement.ToString() + " meters";
    }
}
```

But in order to find out the remaining distance (or displacement which has not traveled yet) you need to at least know the radius of the curve:

*I assumed that the curve is part of a circle*

If the curve is half of a circle, the displacement is **radius × pi**

Else if the angel is known, the displacement is **radius × angel (in radians)**

if angel is unknown but radius and distance is known, the displacement is **2 × radius × arcsin(distance/2 × radius)**

[image]

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer, I understand this. but what if there is an irregular curve like wave or road curve or something like that.

Comment: In that case you need to approximate. or you can make use of libraries such as splines and curves to move your object along its path. the value in those methods refer to the displacement on the path. just google unity spline path

Comment: Actually I should have written on the Question, sorry for that I missed it. I am using Spline to move object. A hermite spline controller.

Comment: I haven't worked with splines myself but if you ask another question and fully describe the situation I'm sure you'll get your answer